# What is the usage of Bernoulli triangle?

Tags: number-theory

I know that Pascal triangle is very usfeul in many fields of mathematics.
I typed in google Bernoulli triangle and couldn't find any usage of it, even on english wikipedia there is not a lot about it.
So what is the usage of Bernoulli triangle ?

Comment: Just a minor point about English: the nearly useless word "usage" almost always means the same as "use". Your use of the word "usage" in asking what is the usage of [the] Bernoulli triangle is a rare case where there is a difference in meaning. You mean "what is the use of the Bernoulli triangle?". I would recommend always using "use" rather than "usage". As to your mathematical question, the Bernoulli triangle gives an interesting tabular representation of sums of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Even though I contributed to [OEIS sequence A008949](https://oeis.org/A008949), I did not recognize it as named Bernoulli triangle. The sequence entry has a single reference that uses that name in its title. Thus, the naming of it as such seems to be  a rare one.